# How do i call LocationActivity from button?

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

I want to call the LocationActivity when the user click on the button and get the location information and set it into my button.

xml file

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/locationTxt"
            android:text="@string/setLocation"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_shape" />
```

Java file

```
public class AddTask extends android.app.Fragment  {
Button btnLocation;

    public AddTask()
    {
        // Constructor
    }
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_task, container, false);
        btnLocation = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.locationTxt);
 btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: use `onActivityResult`. When click on the btnLocation transfer to your LocationActivity and once location work is done set your button text in `onActivityResult` callback method.

Comment: @Kunu how do i transfer to my LocationActivity in the onClick method? Because i not familiar with transferring an activity within fragment

Comment: use `startActivity(getActivity(),LocationActivity.class);`